# Does $-2 \int (\cos^2\,x-\sin^2\,x)\,\sin\,2x\,dx$ have multiple answers?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

After working $-2 \displaystyle\int (\cos^2\,x-\sin^2\,x)\,\sin\,2x\,dx$, I got $\frac{-\sin^2(2x)}{2}+c$. The answer I was given was $\frac{\cos^2(2x)}{2}+c$. Are these both legitimate solutions, depending on if sine or cosine is chosen for substitution?

Comment: They are both equivalent. If you put limits on your integral the $+c$ would be different in each case.

Comment: what do you mean? @GeorgeDewhirst

Comment: Call constant 1from the sine answer $c$ and constant 2 (from the cosine answer) $c'$.



$c' +\frac{1}{2} = c$

Comment: All indefinite integrals have multiple answers.  The answers differ by the famed constant of integration.

Answer (score 0):

$E=\frac{-\sin^2(2x)}{2}+c=\frac{-1+\cos^2(2x)}{2}+c$
$E=\frac{\cos^2(2x)}{2}+c-\frac 1 2=\frac{\cos^2(2x)}{2}+k$

Where $ k=c-\frac 1 2$

These are the same answers.